# Ansible supervisorctl, difference between state 'restarted' and 'present'

Tags: ansible, supervisord

I am deploying a Django app to both production and staging environments (which happen to be in the same server). In order to do that, I run `supervisord` with two different process for both environments.

Thus in my `ansible-playbook`, I template my uwsgi config (according to the environment variables) and copy it to the `/etc/supervisor/conf.d` folder.

Say I want to deploy the first time to a new staging environment. Since there are not any present config files, I would need to `supervisorctl reread` and `supervisorctl update`.

As I read from the [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/supervisorctl_module.html#notes):

> When `state = present`, the module will call `supervisorctl reread` then `supervisorctl add` if the program/group does not exist.
>
> When `state = restarted`, the module will call `supervisorctl update` then call `supervisorctl restart`.

But does it mean I need to call both of them if I want to support both new  staging instances and my current ones? Or is it enough to just use the `state=restarted`? Or am I doing something wrong?

Would this code be ok? Or is it duplicating some information?

```
    - name: Add uwsgi app (reread + add)
      become: yes
      supervisorctl: name={{uwsgi_app}} state=present

    - name: Start uwsgi app (update + restart)
      become: yes
      supervisorctl: name={{uwsgi_app}} state=restarted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to either call both or set in your applications config files (the one you set in `/etc/supervisor/conf.d`) [for the application to start automatically](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-values) by adding a line:

```
autostart: true
```

While it is true by default, I prefer to be explicit.